# Using Terminal Bars to Splice Service Entry Wires

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Based on the second diagram in [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/106189/can-i-feed-2-sub-panels-off-one-breaker%20this) question on feeding two subpanels from a single main breaker panel, I would like to know the best way to split the single feeder cable to two feeder cables for each subpanel.

Because the wires are all 2GA Cu, they appear to be too large for wire nuts and pigtails. Can a terminal bar (like those used for ground/neutral bars) be used for this purpose, to split a single 2GA wire into two 2GA wires?

Comment: To do a T-splice, see my answer [here.](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/106947/47125)

Comment: Ah, that looks like a terminal block but insulated. Thanks.

Comment: How are those secured within a junction box though?

Comment: They just lay there loose, same as a wire nut. The kit comes with plugs that go into the screw holes (really hex key holes) so nothing is exposed.  You are to tighten them down to a specific torque spec, called out in the instructions or molded onto the case.  And then, they're not going anywhere.  Get one whose maximum wire size is your size, so the wire insulation fits fairly snug in the holes.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if they were supposed to be affixed to the box, like a normal terminal block would be.

Comment: @Harper this should be an answer those come in all kinds of sizes, I have used with up to 5 lugs very handy but a little spendy.

Comment: I've actually had trouble finding them. Do they have an actual name? I found some that fit my application, but finding any with more than three terminals, or for relatively large wires is difficult.